# How to use CustomHealthCheck with health_check gem in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

From the `health_check` official site, we know that it can add a `config.add_custom_check` block in the config file:

https://github.com/ianheggie/health_check

```
# Add one or more custom checks that return a blank string if ok, or an error message if there is an error
config.add_custom_check do
  CustomHealthCheck.perform_check # any code that returns blank on success and non blank string upon failure
end

# Add another custom check with a name, so you can call just specific custom checks. This can also be run using
# the standard 'custom' check.
# You can define multiple tests under the same name - they will be run one after the other.
config.add_custom_check('sometest') do
  CustomHealthCheck.perform_another_check # any code that returns blank on success and non blank string upon failure
end
```

But about the `CustomHealthCheck` class, how to define it?

For `okcomputer` gem, it offers a way like this:

https://github.com/sportngin/okcomputer

```
# config/initializers/okcomputer.rb
class MyCustomCheck < OkComputer::Check
  def check
    if rand(10).even?
      mark_message "Even is great!"
    else
      mark_failure
      mark_message "We don't like odd numbers"
    end
  end
end

OkComputer::Registry.register "check_for_odds", MyCustomCheck.new
```

Didn't find the usage about `health_check` gem.

---

## Update

I have tried:

Add these source in the `config/initializers/health_check.rb` file:

```
class CustomHealthCheck
  def perform_check
    if rand(10).even?
      p "Even is great!"
    else                                                                                                            
      p "We don't like odd numbers"
    end
  end
end

HealthCheck.setup do |config|
...
```

Run `curl -v localhost:3000/health_check.json`, got:

```
{"healthy":false,"message":"health_check failed: undefined method `perform_check' for CustomHealthCheck:Class"}%
```

---

## Update 2

Edited source in `config/initializers/health_check.rb`:

```
class CustomHealthCheck
  def self.perform_check
    p 'OK'
  end
end

HealthCheck.setup do |config|
...
```

Got:

```
{"healthy":false,"message":"health_check failed: OK"}%
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're objective and question is. You might want to post some code where you've tried to use this and got an error.

Comment: @mahemoff I don't know how to write the code so asked it.

Comment: Sure but it's just not clear exactly what you're trying to achieve. CustomHealthCheck in the example is just an imaginary class.

Comment: @mahemoff Thank you. I have updated the question and pasted what I tried.

Comment: You've defined `perform_check` as an instance method. If you want it to be a class method, you need to do `def self.perform_check`.

Comment: @jvillian Good, I edited the source and tried again. Posted the code to the question. Not clear how to define `success` or `failure`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Success is defined by returning an empty or blank string. Right now your `perform_check` always returns the string "OK" which will be seen as failure.

Try this to get a passing health check:

```
class CustomHealthCheck
  def self.perform_check
    everything_is_good = true # or call some method to do more elaborate checking
    return everything_is_good ? "" : "We've got Problems"
  end
end
```

Comment: After I tried your code, it got: `{"healthy":false,"message":"health_check failed: no implicit conversion of true into String"}%`.

Comment: @zseikyocho - I corrected my error so it always returns a string now